# Is my PC compromised?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filesystems

Today I was wondering about my least used files on my PC and went ahead to enable the "Date accessed" detail on my file explorer. After enabling the option I noticed something strange: A bunch of files in my downloads folder were accessed during the night (I was using the PC at the time, but didn't touch those files). These files include banner images, installers, crystaldiskmark etc. All accessed files were accessed within the same minute. Is this normal behaviour or should I be worried?

Comment: Do you have search indexer running? If yes, this is very likely to be it.

Comment: Windows Defender occasionally scans files. If they also show up in the downloads list of your browser then it may be that they were "accessed" to see if the files still exist as the browser will grey out items that have been deleted.